# delegated click event not firing when element gets disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

When I bind a click handler to a element which disables that element, then try to delegate another event to it, the second event doesn't fire.

Is there a simple solution to this?

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq69L/)

```
$('button').click(function() {
    log('first click fired');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
$('span').on('click', 'button', function() {
    log('second click fired');
});
```

HTML:

```
<span><button>click</button></span>
```

EDIT:

To clarify, setting a click event on the object itself will fire [**as seen in this edit**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq69L/2/), I want to be able to do that with delegation

Comment: @sircapsalot - no it shouldn't, it's a property, not an attribute!

Comment: @sircapsalot actually that would be `$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')` but I'm using `prop` instead which is setting a `javascipt` prop on the DOM element

Comment: maybe i'm still ignorant of the differences between them... gah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabled elements does not fire mouse events, as they are ... wait for it ... disabled.

Since they don't fire mouse events, no event bubbles to the span, and the event handler never triggers.

The solution is to not disable the element, and it's pretty much the only solution as far as I know, but if you explain why you need this behaviour maybe someone can help you with a workaround?

**EDIT:**

It does seem to work if you create your own delegation:

```
$('span').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button')
        log('second click fired');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qq69L/3/)

Comment: I realize why this is happening, I want to know if there is a workaround, currently I'm setting a timeout to disable the element but that seems hacky

Comment: There is no real workaround as you can not make disabled elements fire mouse events no matter what you do, but a timeout would work as a hack, and a better approach would be to disable the element in the last event handler.

Comment: see edit on the question, is it possible if the event was bound on the element.